# Keycloak admin API flow bindings

Tags: keycloak

I've created custom authorization flow and I'd like to change browser binding flow to this custom made with API call.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured that out if anyone's interested.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $KEYCLOAK_TOKEN" -d '{"browserFlow": "Custom flow"}' 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/'
```